# How can I add an upload form onto the checkout of woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, woocommerce

I'm trying to add an upload form onto the checkout of my woocommerce website...I have a found a good tutorial here: http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/snippets/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-hooks-and-filters/ which shows how to customize the fields, however within the array there is not an option to create an upload form only (type of field (text, textarea, password, select).

How could I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I can't answer about the woocommerce perspective. But as your problem is about `upload` functionality I recommend you [valums / file-uploader](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader). I have use it in all my last WP plugins, both the front and backend.

> This plugin uses an XMLHttpRequest (AJAX) for uploading multiple files
>   with a progress-bar in FF3.6+, Safari4+, Chrome and falls back to
>   hidden-iframe-based upload in other browsers (namely IE), providing
>   good user experience everywhere.

It is a little hard to make it work, but once you have accomplished you will love it.So if you want give it a try and need help ask again here in SO. And redirect it to me so I can be informed to help you.

Comment: thank you, it's just trying to link it to the add to cart button on woocommerce etc.

Answer (score 0):

I use a file upload in each of my products - gravity forms allows this - though there is one limitation of the filesize as default being about 8mb - though I'm told this can be increased.

I use woo commerce - and there is an extension for gravity forms - which makes adding these forms to products (or anything else) really easy.

Only downside is no upload bar or showing the uploaded file...

Answer (score 0):

**For form, try to use these two hooks:**

1) add_action('woocommerce_after_cart_table', 'add_file_to_upcoming_order');

2) add_action('woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details', 'add_file_to_upcoming_order');

**And to receive/get files, you should use hooks like the following:**

```
add_action('woocommerce_init', 'file_during_checkout');
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending', 'wc_checkout_order_processed'); 
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_on-hold', 'wc_checkout_order_processed');
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'wc_checkout_order_processed');
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'wc_checkout_order_processed');
```

**Important:**
    add_action( 'save_post', 'pre_wc_checkout_order_processed' );

**Description:**
In fact you can loose your attachments when your hook will be depending on order status. Suppose your order is not completed in anyway so you will loose the PHP session too. Its better that you manage with "save_post" hook and must add some flags to your upload attachments.

You can use this function [wp_handle_upload](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload) to handle your uploaded files. Once files are uploaded so you can easily get order items from WooCommerce object "WC_Order" & $order->get_items() which were added previously. I tried to make it working [last year](http://www.websitedesignwebsitedevelopment.com/wufdc) and a number of people used it too, you can develop an improved solution by using these hooks.